# Add additional MIME types using .hataccess & PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess

When i am download a file from my webserver php fetch the MIME types so the browser knows what to open the file with. On my website a have a mixture of file types.

I would like to add a MIME type to the list PHP recognise:

This is how my server download a file using PHP to a computer:

```
if (file_exists($file)) {
header( 'Cache-Control: public' );
      header( 'Content-Description: File Transfer' );
      header( "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename={$file}" );
      header( 'Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file) );
      header( 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary' );
      readfile( $file );
      exit;
}
```

Now some website sugestion you can add MIME types using .hatacces files
http://www.htaccess-guide.com/adding-mime-types/

So this is what i put in my htacces folder so that it recognise viso file formats:

```
AddType application/x-viso .vsdx
```

When i download a viso file from the server it doesn't recognise it a viso file using Firefox. I do have viso install. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try `AddType text/x-visio .vsdx` instead

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.